# Vim Autocommand pattern to match rspec.rb files?

Tags: autocmd, pattern

I am trying to trigger rspec each time I save a file, but none of the patterns I gave trigger the command. What did I do wrong?

I am using the [vim-rspec](https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec) and [dispatch.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch). The rspec commands run fine, the problem that I'm having is finding a pattern to match the autocommand.

The following runs fine:

```
augroup rspec_run | au!
  au BufWritePost * call RunNearestSpec()
augroup end
```

The pattern above is set to match any file `*`. Ideally it should match only files ending with _spec.rb (spec/models/foo_spec.rb, spec/controllers/bar_controller_spec.rb, etc)

I tried `*_spec.rb` and `**/*_spec.rb` to no avail. How can I set the pattern to match rspec files?

Comment: `*_spec.rb` should work.

Comment: You're right. I tried it again and it works now. I must have done something incorrect when I initially tried it the other day. Thank you!